# Python - shortening a redundant loop

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

How could I shorten this loop with 4 redundant if statements?

This code is meant to count how many cards of each suit is in a player's hand in a card game:

```
suitcounter = [0, 0, 0, 0]
if len(hand) > 0:
    for card in hand:
        if card[1] == "C":
            suitcounter[0] += 1
        if card[1] == "D":
            suitcounter[1] += 1
        if card[1] == "S":
            suitcounter[2] += 1
        if card[1] == "H":
            suitcounter[3] += 1
return suitcounter
```

#### Example:

Hand consists of two hearts and one spade:

```
>>>hand = ['3H', '4H', 'AS']
[0, 0, 1, 2]
```

`3H` = 3 of hearts, `4H` = 4 of hearts, `AS` = Ace of spades.

I feel there's just too much code 'spam' in what I've done. WTB tips.

Comment: Just a tip: You don't need to check that the length of the hand is greater than zero, as zero is falsey anyway, so `if len(hand):` does the same thing.

Comment: @CarlSmith except that you can skip that check completely, as the loop will terminate without iteration for empty `hand`, anyway.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking more generally, but yeah, `+1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
suitcounter = [0, 0, 0, 0]
suits = {'C': 0, 'D': 1, 'S': 2, 'H': 3}

for card in hand:
    suitcounter[suits[card[1]]] += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make `suitcounter` a dict:

```
suitcounter_d = {"C":0,"D":0, "S":0 ,"H":0}

for card in hand:
    suitcounter_d[card[1]] += 1
```

Also checking the length is redundant as if it is < 1 there will be no loop.

If you want some order to the output use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
suitcounter_d = OrderedDict((('C', 0), ('D', 0), ('S', 0), ('H', 0)))

for card in hand:
    suitcounter_d[card[1]] += 1
```

So putting it in your function and returning as in your example is simple, just access the dict values:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def suit_out(hand):
    suit_count_dict = OrderedDict((('C', 0), ('D', 0), ('S', 0), ('H', 0)))
    for card in hand:
        suit_count_dict[card[1]] += 1
    return list(suit_count_dict.values())

print(suit_out(['3H', '4H', 'AS']))
[0, 0, 1, 2]
```

If you use .items you will get a suit/count pairing as output in tuples:

```
return list(suit_count_dict.items())
print(suit_out(['3H', '4H', 'AS']))

[('C', 0), ('D', 0), ('S', 1), ('H', 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using collections module:

> `class collections.Counter([iterable-or-mapping])` A Counter is a dict
>   subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an unordered collection
>   where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are
>   stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be any integer
>   value including zero or negative counts. The Counter class is similar
>   to bags or multisets in other languages.

```
import collections

def count_suites(cards):
    suits = (card[1] for card in cards)
    return collections.Counter(suits)
```

In a similar way you may count cards by value:

```
import collections

def count_values(cards):
    values = (card[0] for card in cards)
    return collections.Counter(values)
```

Sample usage and outputs:

```
cards = ['3H', '4H', 'AS']
print count_suites(cards)  # Counter({'H': 2, 'S': 1})
print count_values(cards)  # Counter({'A': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1})
```